# SOAP HTTP not found

Tags: php, soap

I am having errors with Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found

here is my code

```
$client = new SOAPClient ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl');
$infoHash = $client->cacheTorrent(base64_encode(file_get_contents('my.torrent')));
```

and here is the WSDL

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<definitions name='Cache'
  targetNamespace='urn:Torcache'
  xmlns:tns='urn:Torcache'
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<message name='cacheTorrentRequest'>
  <part name='torrent' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>

<message name='cacheTorrentResponse'>
  <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>

<portType name='CachePortType'>
  <operation name='cacheTorrent'>
    <input message='tns:cacheTorrentRequest'/>
    <output message='tns:cacheTorrentResponse'/>
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name='CacheBinding' type='tns:CachePortType'>
  <soap:binding style='rpc'
    transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

  <operation name='cacheTorrent'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#cacheTorrent'/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>

<service name='CacheService'>
  <port name='CachePort' binding='CacheBinding'>
    <soap:address location='http://torcache.net/api/soap/'/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

My server stats

PHP version 5.3.15

Any idea why I am getting this error? I have got this sample script from their api page
https://torcache.net/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never gotten remote Wsdl to load with php's soapclient.  To test, try downloading the wsdl to a local file and use an absolute file path from root '/' instead of a url. If it works fine, as i expect, you'll be at least sure its not your fault, but sure it a bug in the library.  I think no one in the php dev world cares about soap anymore and no one is addressing the issue.  Or maybe we are just missing something obvious....

If you don't mind php 5.3 deprecated warnings you can find a copy of the old nusoap library and use that--it loads remote wsdls without any issue.